# Ubuntu 22.04 Casper kernel parameters not working for VLAN Tag

Tags: grub2, 22.04, uefi, autoinstall

I'm set up using Foreman and Grub2 to serve Grub2 template for UEFI HTTP Boot.  This configuration works just fine on my server(s) and I've built unattended Ubuntu 22.04 servers using autoinstall and userdata.  Everything works great until I try to introduce VLAN ID to the kernel parameters.  There is little to none documentation on how to do this with Casper.  I'm stuck at the point before Subiquity (Userdata) step occurs.  Here is my grub2 template:

```bash
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
    set gfxmode=auto
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod gfxterm
    terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/light-blue
set menu_color_highlight=light-blue/light-gray
set timeout=10
set default=0

menuentry "Ubuntu 22.04" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    echo "Loading Kernel..."
    linuxefi boot/ubuntu-22-04-smartproxy-iHSnrxJrt5ql-vmlinuz BOOT=casper vlan=846:enp69s0f0np0 ip=<ip>::<gw>:<mask>:<hostname>:enp69s0f0np0.846:none:<DNSip1>:<DNSIP2>  cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://<foremanproxy>/media/ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds="nocloud-net;s=http://<foremanproxy>/userdata/"
    echo "Loading initial ramdisk..."
    initrdefi boot/ubuntu-22-04-smartproxy-iHSnrxJrt5ql-initrd
}
```

[image: Terminal Window VLAN Tag Failure]

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/casper.7.html doesn't have anything about static ip or vlan configuration.  I have to make assumptions based on https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/dracut.cmdline.7.html

Comment: Grub2 Template snippet with VLAN param but Casper still uses VLAN 0:
`linuxefi boot/ubuntu-22-04-smartproxy-iHSnrxJrt5ql-vmlinuz vlan=699:enp69s0f0np0 ip=<hostip>::<gw>:<mask>:<hostname>:enp69s0f0np0:none:<DNS1>:<DNS2> cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://<foreman>/media/ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds="nocloud-net;s=http://<foreman>/userdata/"
    echo "Loading initial ramdisk..."
    initrdefi boot/ubuntu-22-04-smartproxy-iHSnrxJrt5ql-initrd
}`

Comment: With the above grub2, the console output shows:
`8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
8021q: adding VLAN 0 to HW filter on device enp69s0f0np0`

This is confirmation the vlan kernel param is doing something, but it's just not passing in the value of the VLAN ID.  This is the only grub2 example that has yielded the 802.1q console output but still not the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

The answer for this is too simple although it took a lot of time to figure out.  The kernel has a character limit on an interface name.  Our predictable interface names (newest standard) was too long for the kernel when appended with vlan info.

Here's a working grub2 linuxefi with vlan and ip params:

```
linuxefi boot/ubuntu-22-04-smartproxy-iHSnrxJrt5ql-vmlinuz vlan=vlan.846:enp69s0f0np0 ip=<hostip>::<gw>:<mask>:<hostname>:vlan.846:none:<dns1>:<dns2> cloud-config-url=/dev/null url=http://<foreman>/media/ubuntu/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso autoinstall ds="nocloud-net;s=http://<foreman>/userdata/"
```